# Postgres function error at or near array error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am get following error in my code

> syntax error at or near "ARRAY"

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."services_auth_data";

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.get_services_auth_data;

create table "public"."services_auth_data" (
    "service_name" text not null,
    "token" text not null,
    "admin_email" text, 
    "org" text
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_services_auth_data(services TEXT[])
RETURNS SETOF services_auth_data AS $$
DECLARE
  email TEXT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'email');
  workspace_name TEXT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'hd');
  name TEXT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'name');
  is_admin BOOLEAN := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'isAdmin')::BOOLEAN;
  w_id BIGINT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'workspace_id')::BIGINT;
  service_result services_auth_data;
  results services_auth_data[] := '{}';
  _token text;
  _org text;
  _admin_email text; 
  service_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR service_name IN ARRAY services LOOP
    IF service_name = 'github' THEN
      SELECT service_github.org, service_github.token INTO _org, _token FROM service_github WHERE id = w_id;
      service_result.org = _org;
      service_result.token = _token;
      service_result.service_name = service_name;
      results := array_append(results, service_result);
    ELSIF service_name = 'jira' THEN
      SELECT service_jira.admin_email, service_jira.token INTO _admin_email, _token FROM service_jira WHERE id = w_id;
      service_result.admin_email = _admin_email;
      service_result.token = _token;
      service_result.service_name = service_name;
      results := array_append(results, service_result);
    ELSIF service_name = 'zoom' THEN
      SELECT service_zoom.token INTO _token FROM service_zoom WHERE id = w_id;
      service_result.token = _token;
      service_result.service_name = service_name;
      results := array_append(results, service_result);
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid service name or missing params: %', service_name;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  return query select * from unnest(results);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am new to writing code, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The only arrays in my code happen to be this   `results services_auth_data[] := '{}';` and `services Text[]`

Does anyone have why I am getting this error?

Comment: If the below answer resolved your issue then please accept it. Do so may help future questioners with the same/similar issues. It also removes the question from the unanswered queue. If it did not solve your issue then update your question to indicate the remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error message applies to the first line of the block

```sql
  FOR service_name IN ARRAY services LOOP
```

You need the `FOREACH` loop to iterate through the elements of an array value, see [Looping through Arrays.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)